# Advantages to randomizing an order status URL?

Tags: url, rest

Is there an advantage in randomizing the URL for order statuses?

Right now, the URL is based on an incrementing order number, like `blah.com/orderstatus/1`, `blah.com/orderstatus/2` and only the user is able to see his own order.  If he tries to look at somebody else's order by changing the number in the url, he will receive an error.

Are there any disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: So long as the user can't change the number and see an order they're not authorised to see, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is good, in fact almost every website use index like that.

Using a random index will make it very complicated, and is absolutely not recommended.